# Casting a finset to finType in Coq/Ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm learning Ssreflect and I wish to know how to solve this situation. My idea is to define a graph (as a Record), and then generate another graph. Below, I show a piece of code (which I extracted from a larger one) that speaks for itself:

```
Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrfun.
From mathcomp Require Import eqtype ssrnat fintype finset.

Section Example.

Record ugraph := UGraph { T : finType ;
                          V : {set T} ;
                          E : {set {set T}} ;
        edges_have_vertices : forall e : {set T}, e \in E -> e \subset V ;
             edges_size_two : forall e : {set T}, e \in E -> #|e| == 2}.

Variable G : ugraph.

Definition closed_neigh : T G -> {set T G} := fun u => [set v | [set u; v] \in E G] :|: [set u].
Notation "N[ x ]" := (closed_neigh x) (at level 0, x at level 99).

Definition T_Gp := prod_finType (T G) (T G).

(* V' is the set of (u, v) such that u \in V and v \in N[u] *)
Definition V_Gp := [set x : T_Gp | (x.1 \in V G) && (x.2 \in (N[x.1]))].

(* E' is the set of edges {uv, zr} such that uv, zr \in V', uv != zr and z \in N[v] *)
Definition E_Gp := [set e : {set T_Gp} | [exists x : T_Gp, [exists y : T_Gp, (e == [set x; y]) && (x != y) && (x \in V_Gp) && (y \in V_Gp) && (y.1 \in N[x.2])]]].

Lemma edges_have_vertices_Gp : forall e : {set T_Gp}, e \in E_Gp -> e \subset V_Gp.
Admitted.

Lemma edges_size_two_Gp : forall e : {set T_Gp}, e \in E_Gp -> #|e| == 2.
Admitted.

Definition gen_Gp := @UGraph T_Gp V_Gp E_Gp edges_have_vertices_Gp edges_size_two_Gp.

End Example.
```

Note that I currently use a *finType T* and, then, the set of vertices is somehow a subset of T. However, I feel that I can take advantage by considering the set of vertices as a finType itself, and avoids the proof of "edges_have_vertices", as follows:

```
Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrfun.
From mathcomp Require Import eqtype ssrnat fintype finset.

Section Example.

Record ugraph := UGraph { V : finType ;
                          E : {set {set V}} ;
             edges_size_two : forall e : {set V}, e \in E -> #|e| == 2}.

Variable G : ugraph.

Definition closed_neigh : V G -> {set V G} := fun u => [set v | [set u; v] \in E G] :|: [set u].
Notation "N[ x ]" := (closed_neigh x) (at level 0, x at level 99).

Definition V_Gp := [set x : prod_finType (V G) (V G) | (x.1 \in V G) && (x.2 \in (N[x.1]))].

Definition E_Gp := [set e : {set V_Gp} | ...]. (* <--- error *)
```

But then, I get an error about V_Gp (the set of vertices of the new graph) should have a type finType instead of {set _}. Is there a way to "convert" V_Gp in a finType?

Comment: I am not sure this approach will get you very far, anyways the idea is that you need to build the type of the elements of the set, one [bad] way to do this is `Definition E_Gp := [set e : seq_sub (enum V_Gp) | true ].`

Comment: I would agree with Emilio. This representation does not seem to be idiomatic for Mathcomp.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. This idea came when I saw another definition of graphs (based on an adjacency function instead of giving the set of edges) here:
https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.pous/covece/k4tw2/coq/TwoPoint.sgraph.html#lab13
where the authors also use V as a finType itself. But I didn't find in their code how to deal with this situation.

Comment: I think that by using "sig_finType" and "val" can work. In my case:

`Definition V_Gp := sig_finType (fun x => x \in [set x : prod_finType (V G) (V G) | (x.1 \in V G) && (x.2 \in (N[x.1]))]).`

`Definition E_Gp := [set e : {set V_Gp} |
  [exists x : V_Gp, [exists y : V_Gp, (e == [set x; y]) && (x != y) && (x \in V_Gp) && (y \in V_Gp) && ((val y).1 \in N[(val x).2])]]].`